# Universal cover of $(S^1\times S^3)\# (S^1\times S^3)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

How can we determine the universal cover of $(S^1\times S^3)\# (S^1\times S^3)$, or more generally of 
$$
X_k:=\overset{k}{\underset{i=1}{\#}}(S^1\times S^3)
$$ 
for $k\in \mathbb{N}$?

The case $X_1$ I am able to compute: $\tilde{X}_1\cong \mathbb{R}\times S^3$.

For $n>1$, according to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93282/homotopy-groups-of-connected-sums), $\tilde{X}_k$ is obtained by "appropriately" gluing the universal covers of $(S^1\times S^3)\setminus \{\mathrm{pt}\}$. What is the appropriate gluing in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: It is the complement to Cantor set in $S^4$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Thank you for your interesting comment. Would you mind elaborating a bit, please? In particular, how do you know such a Cantor set must exist, and do you know an explicit description of the set?

Comment: I will, in a few days. The proof uses some hyperbolic geometry. Are you familiar with it?

Comment: @MoisheKohan: I am familiar with some parts of the theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a collection of pairwise disjoint closed round balls $B_i, B_i', i=1,...,k,$ in $S^n$. Let $F$ denote the closure of the complement
$$
S^n - \bigcup_{i=1}^k (B_i\cup B_i'). 
$$
The boundary of $F$ has standard orientation induced from $F$. The boundary of $F$ is a disjoint union of 
round sphere $S_i=\partial B_i, S'_i=\partial B'_i$. Let $h_i: S_i\to S'_i, i=1,...,k$ be orientation-reversing diffeomorphisms. 
Let $M$ denote the $n$-dimensional manifold obtained by gluing boundary spheres of $F$ via   the maps $h_i, i=1,..,k$. 
It is a pleasant exercise to verify that $M$ is diffeomorphic to the $k$-fold connected sum of $S^n\times S^1$.

I now impose more conditions on the maps $h_i$:  I will assume that all these are *Moebius transformations* of $S^n$. 
If you consider $S^n$ as the boundary of the unit ball model of the hyperbolic space ${\mathbb H}^{n+1}$ 
then extensions of isometries of ${\mathbb H}^{n+1}$ are precisely the Moebius transformations of $S^n$.

Let $G$ denote the group of Moebius transformations of $S^n$ generated by $h_1,...,h_k$. One verifies (by induction on word-length) 
that $G$ is a free group on the generating set $h_1,...,h_k$ and that $F$ is a *fundamental domain* of $G$: The intersection 
$gF\cap F$ is either $F$ (precisely when $g=1$) or is a boundary sphere of $F$ (precisely when $g=h_i^{\pm 1}$ for some $i$) 
or is empty.

Assuming that $n\ge 3$, the domain $F$ is simply-connected and so is the union
$$
\Omega=\bigcup_{g\in G} gF. 
$$
Thus, $\Omega$ is equivariantly diffeomorphic to the universal covering space of the manifold $M$. The domain $\Omega$ 
is the *discontinuity domain* of the group $G$. The complement $\Lambda=S^n -\Omega$ is the *limit set* of $G$. 
One verifies that $\Lambda$ is totally disconnected and perfect (contains no isolated points) provided that $k\ge 2$ which I will assume from now on.

One way to prove it is as follows: Let $G_L$ denote the subset of $G$ consisting of words of length $\le L$ in  the generators 
$h_i^{\pm 1}$, $i=1,...,k$. Then observe that the boundary of the union
$$
F_L= \bigcup_{g\in G_L} gF
$$ 
consists of round spheres of radii $\le r_L$ and $\lim_{L\to\infty} r_L=0$. 
Thus, $\Lambda$ is homeomorphic to the classical Cantor set.

One can do a bit better. Fix a round circle $S^1\subset S^n$ and assume that the spheres $S_i, S_i'$ are chosen to be orthogonal to $S^1$. Then the Moebius transformations $h_i$ can be chosen to preserve the circle $S^1$. It follows that the limit set $\Lambda$ is contained in $S^1$. Identify $S^n$ with the 1-point compactification of ${\mathbb R}^n$  and choose $S^1$ to be the one-point compactification of a straight line ${\mathbb R}^1$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$. Then there exists a homeomorphism $f: S^n\to S^n$ 
sending $S^1$ to itself and sending $\Lambda$ to the standard ternary Cantor subset $K$ of ${\mathbb R}^1$.

We conclude that the universal covering space of $M$ is homeomorphic to ${\mathbb R}^n \cup \{\infty\} - K$.

You can find more details in Chapter "Schottky Dance" in

"[Indra's Pearls: The Vision of Felix Klein](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521352533)" 
by David Mumford, Caroline Series and David Wright.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One question about how this construction depends on $k$: since the homeomorphism type of the universal cover of $M$ depends on $k$, I think the limit sets $\Lambda$ *cannot* be homeomorphic for different values of $k$; however, your answer seems to indicate that $\Lambda$ is homeomorphic to the classical Cantor set *for any $k\geq 2$* (in particular, the homeomorphism type of $\Lambda$ is independent of $k$). Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: It does not depend on $k$ if $k\ge 2$.

Comment: One more thing: Taking a finite index subgroup does not change the limit set. Thus, you see that the limit set does not depend on $k$.

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental group is a free group of rank $k$, as one can see by applying Van Kampen's Theorem.

Therefore, the "appropriate" gluing pattern is to take the universal cover of a rank $k$ rose, which is a tree with every vertex of valence $2k$, then to place a copy of $\overset{k}{\underset{i=1}{\#}}([0,1]\times S^3)$ at each vertex, which is a 4-manifold with boundary whose boundary has $2k$ components, each homeomorphic to $S^3$, and then to glue together a pair of these $S^3$ boundaries for each edge, one $S^3$ boundary from one endpoint of the edge and the other $S^3$ boundary from the opposite endpoint of the edge.

Comment: I'm confused here, for the case $k=1$ I thought it's its own universal cover??? It is simply connected, having trivial fundamental group.

Comment: When $k=1$, we have $\pi_1(X_1) \approx \pi_1(S^1 \times S^3) \approx \pi_1(S^1) \times \pi_1(S^3) \approx \mathbb Z \oplus \text{Id} \approx \mathbb Z$. So no, $X_1$ is not simply connected. In this case the tree is $\mathbb R$ subdivided at the integers, and the resulting universal cover is $\mathbb R \times S^3$.

Comment: Pardon me, I'm coming from a physics background, but I thought $\pi_{1}(S^3)=0$ making the product zero. I must be misinterpreting something. intuitively I get that it's not simply connected

Comment: I totally understand that we could put a loop orthogonal to a foliation of three-sphere surfaces around $S^1$ and not be able to shrink it.

Comment: You should think of the trivial group as an identity element under the operation of direct sum: $A \oplus 0$ is isomorphic to $A$. Also, in group theory, the direct product and direct sum are identical as long as you are using a finite number of terms, so $A \times B$ is simply an alternate notation for $A \oplus B$.