# Infinitely generated $\pi_2(M)$ where $M$ is closed smooth manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, higher-homotopy-groups

I am looking for a closed smooth manifold with infinitely generated $\pi_2$. I know there is an easy example with some universal cover i think, but all i have in my head is $S^2\vee S^1$, which is not even a topological manifold...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interested aswell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the complex projective plane $\mathbb{CP}^2$ and take a connected sum with a $4$-torus, i.e. take $X = \mathbb{CP}^2 \# (S^1)^4$. This is a closed $4$-manifold. Its universal cover $\tilde{X}$ is a connected sum of copies of countably many $\mathbb{CP}^2$ (which is simply connected) so $\pi_2(X) = \pi_2(\tilde{X}) = H_2(\tilde{X})$ is a direct sum of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ and is therefore not finitely generated.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Ths may come a little late now, but is it correct that $\tilde{X}$ is the connected sum of copies of $\mathbb{CP}^2$? I have the plane with countably many $\mathbb{CP}^2$s in my head. And in the case of only two $\mathbb{CP}^2$ I don't think that's the same as $\mathbb{CP}^2\#\mathbb{CP}^2$. Proof stays the same. Thanks again for the fast reply!

Comment: You're right now that I think of it, it's the connected sum of copies of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ with a point removed if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: In the case of two $\mathbb{CP}^2$ that is correct for sure. I need to think about it a little bit in the general case I guess. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: In fact it's $\mathbb{R}^4$ with a copy of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ "connected summed" to each integer point. That's what I had in mind at first, but somehow I thought that was the connected sum of copies of $\mathbb{CP}^2$; it is if you add the point at infinity, but it's not actually there of course.

Comment: An example which is easier to visualize is $^2\times ^1\#^2\times ^1$. The universal cover is $^3$  minus Cantor set; [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305192/universal-cover-of-s1-times-s3-s1-times-s3/3342555#3342555).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Don't mind me calling $\mathbb{R}^4$ a "plane"..., but I think I got it now. Thanks!

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks for the refference I'll look into it.